# Random Number from 0 to 1000 Math.random()

Tags: java

Currently making a program for homework and I am confused regarding one aspect of the normal formula that is usually used

`Math.random() * (max - min) + min`

I understand that this would work perfectly fine with a range of `1 - 1000` for example.

Now, sorry for my ignorance and if this comes out as a stupid question... but if I want a range from `0 - 1000`, would this still work?

Since the range `1 - 1000` would set `(max - min)` as 999, then multiply by `Math.random()` and then add `min`... range `0 - 1000` would set `(max - min)` as 1000 and would not add anything at the end since its still 0. Would this still work if I have `min` as 0 and `max` as 1000? Or would I have to go through a different route/formula?

Comment: For the range `0 - 1000`, should the `1000` be INCLUDED or not as one of the possible values that can be returned?

Comment: If you want to INCLUDE both "min" and "max", then you should be using this formula: `(int) (Math.random()*(max-min + 1))+min;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the formula to see if it helps!

Given that [`Math.random()` returns a double which has value 0 <= value < 1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#random()), when:

- `min = 1`, the formula returns values between 1 (`0 * (1000 - 1) + 1 = 1`) and 999 (`0.999999... * (1000 - 1) + 1 = 999`)
- `min = 0`, the formula returns values between 0 (`0 * (1000 - 0) + 0 = 0`) and 999 (`0.999999... * (1000 - 0) + 0 = 999`)

So, `min = 0` works as you'd expect but it seems like you're missing a **+1** in the formula's range term:

Generating an integer random number in a range with Math.random() is done by this formula:
`(int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min`

Comment: So if I were to go ahead with min = 0 and max = 1000, by adding that +1 , I would be able to generate the random number on the range of 0 to 1000? So multiplying 0.99999999 * 1001 would give me that range?

Comment: yes, because the result would be something like 1000.999998999 and then it'd be converted to int which would get rid off the decimals and return 1000. Then add 0 (min) to that and you have 1000

Comment: int number = (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1) + min);

I imagine this would be the way that I would have to put it in the code right?

Answer (score 1):

Math.random() returns random nr range 0 to 1, so to get range 0 to 1000 all you need to do is to multiply by 1000. No need to add anything, so the formula will still work

Comment: 1 is NOT included in the possible return values from `Math.random()`, so 1000 would not be possible if you simply multiply by 1000.

Comment: Correct - 1000 is the upper limit not included but this concerns any range obtainted by the given formula